# What is a complex line, equation/function wise?

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry

A complex line is the image of a linear function, L : $\mathbb{C}$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{C}^{n}$.

In real sense, a real-line is an equation given by $Ax+By+C$ = $0$. Why does complex line not an equation but a function? I am having a hard time for understanding this.

Thanks!

Comment: Who says a real line is an equation? A line is a point set in any case, real or complex

Comment: oh i see.. thanks.. somehow that comment did it for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mathematics there is often more than one way to represent the same data.  For example the line $y=mx+b$ is the same set of points as the image of $L(t) = (t, mt+b)$.  However an equation $Ax+By+c=0$ can only represent a line in $\mathbb{C}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^2$.  The higher dimensional analog of this equation would represent a plane (with 3 variables) or a hyper plane (with more than 3 variables).